# Criar novos usuários com Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

Executei o make:auth do laravel 5.3 mas quando estou criando novos usuários perco minha sessão e o novo usuário fica logado. Alguém sabe como posso criar um novo usuário e continuar logado com minha conta?

Comment: Como você está criando os novos usuário, poste o código!

Comment: Não mexi na lógica que o próprio laravel já utiliza. Modifiquei apenas as views.

Comment: Este form padrão é para "auto cadastro", por assim dizer, para ter acesso ao sistema, para fazer um CRUD de usuários, crie um outro form e popule no banco de dados, este é apenas para autenticação...

Comment: @DavidCoelho pensei que tinha desenvolvido algo, mas, esse código é assim: você cadastra, e automáticamente fica logado no site, é como se fosse para E-Commerce por exemplo. Tem que criar um para área interna do seu site, então. mãos a obra!

Comment: Entendido. Pessoal muito obrigado! Abraço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode desabilitar essa opção dentro do arquivo de registro padrão do framework:

```
MeuProjeto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php
```

Esta é o método que realiza o registro:

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        // Esta linha loga no usuário recém criado
        // Comente-a para não realizar o login
        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```